# Maven `mvn -PautoInstallPackage clean install` fail from VM guest to host

Tags: java, maven, virtualbox, aem

**TLDR;**

The following command fails to run in Virtual Box guest OS to build and install an artifact onto an AEM 6.3 Author instance running on the host OS.

```
mvn -PautoInstallPackage clean install
```

The host machine is behind a corporate proxy and guest OS has CNTLM and Maven proxy file configured.

**Longer version**

I use a VirtualBox VM for development - mainly to mitigate corporate software installation restrictions. Trying to run the following command to build and deploy an AEM 6.3 multi module project, but it keeps failing. The following is the maven command:

```
mvn -PautoInstallPackage clean install
```

And the build stop running beyond this point:

```
[INFO] Discarding unexpected response: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

When I run the same command with the debug flag (`-X`), I get the following lines before the error:

```
...
[DEBUG] Request body sent
[DEBUG] << "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[DEBUG] << "[\r][\n]"
[INFO] Discarding unexpected response: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

Some key details of my setup:

- Host OS is Windows 7 Enterprise - *this is where my AEM 6.3 Author instance is running*
- Guest OS is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS - *this is where I do development*
- The computer is connected to a network that sits behind a corporate proxy
- Proxy is setup on VM guest with CNTLM, `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` env variables and `~/.m2/settings.xml` for Maven
- Maven can fetch all dependencies from Internet without any issue
- All other commands like `npm install`, `curl` work fine fetching content from Internet
- I have added `10.*` to the white-list in both CNTLM and Maven `settings.xml` file
- In Virtual Box settings I have added the Host-only Adapter
- I can connect to the AEM instance running on host OS through browser via http://10.0.2.2:4502

Full error log file: https://paste.ee/p/dph1n

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide more logs for error? Which plugin and what action produced such error?

Comment: @YuriyAlevohin - I have uploaded the error log here https://paste.ee/p/dph1n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deploying to AEM on the host from within a VM does not require a proxy at all.

Try setting `<useProxy>false</useProxy>` in the configuration section of the Content Package maven plugin. See [content-package-maven-plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/vlt-mavenplugin.html) docs for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

What I see in logs:

- plugin `content-package-maven-plugin` tries to send compiled project to http://10.0.2.2:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp`
- plugin uses `Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1` for HTTP
- plugin set property `http.protocol.expect-continue = true` in HttpClient which means it could handle HTTP response `100-Continue` in a proper way
- After sending headers of HTTP request plugin/HttpClient wait for `100-Continue` during timeout 5 seconds (`Set parameter http.connection.timeout = 5000` in log https://paste.ee/p/dph1n#s=0&l=2481)
- No response from servere during 5 seconds (probably, no timestamps in logs). Message in log `[INFO] 100 (continue) read timeout. Resume sending the request` https://paste.ee/p/dph1n#s=0&l=2500
- plugin/HttpClient send HTTP request body
- server return unexpected response with `100-continue`. Unexpected because client already not waiting for it.

Try to increase `timeout` in `content-package-maven-plugin` configuration (https://paste.ee/p/dph1n#s=0&l=2448). Probably 5 seconds is not enouph to get response from server.

**UPDATED**
I'm not sure if you are using squid as proxy (port 3128 in your logs). But if it's true you can try use workaround - disable passing request's header `Expect: 100-continue` on proxy as described here http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.1/cfgman/ignore_expect_100.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response. I will try this out and let you know. I'm only using CNTLM  as an authentication proxy (`localhost:3128`).